# How to iterate into an array inside of an if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to add values to an array via a condition within an if function. Here is the estate agent in question along with the other parts that I want to integrate:

```
function keyDown(e){
    var arr= [];
    if(initialTime== 0){
        
        return;
    }
    
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        ship.move(-25, 0);
            
    }
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        ship.move(25,0);
    }
    if(shipX == enemyX1 && e.keycode== Keyboard.letter('a')){
        scoreCount();
    }
    if(shipX == enemyX2 && e.keycode== Keyboard.letter('a')){
        scoreCount2();
    }
    }
    function scoreCount(){
        arr.push(60);
    }

    function scoreCount2(){
        arr.push(20);
    }
```

In this code, I'm trying to get it so that when the x coordinate of the ship object equals the x coordinate of either enemy 1 or 2 and the letter a is pressed that it'll iterate a  score of either 60 or 20 into an array. I will then add up all instances of this array at the end of the program to see if the user has failed or won the game.

I've gotten to the point where it just prints the first value of 60 over and over again and using a return stops that but I wanted to count each individual time that the if the condition is met and put that into the array and then add up of all the values in the array to get a final score. Any insight on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a switch case ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with the term "case" is it like an if statement? And if so could I use it like one?  I am a novice at this sort of stuff and does switch mean that it chooses between the numerous cases based on whether they are true or not?

Comment: there is a sample code in the documentation, you can test it by your self

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should declare the "arr" variable outside the keyDown function. I think your code is always reinitializing the variable so you only see the first value.

Sorry can't add a comment bcoz of my reputation.